# How many years of millisecond timestamps can be represented by 41 bits?

Tags: math, time, timestamp, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

I'm looking at the [Instagram blog post about sharded ID generation](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram). This blog post describes generating 64-bit identifiers. Their mechanism allocates 41 of the 64 bits to a millisecond timestamp, and they say:

> - 41 bits for time in milliseconds (gives us 41 years of IDs with a custom epoch)

Is this a typo? I calculated that you can store 69 years of millisecond timestamps in 41 bits. Here's how:

- Max milliseconds stored in 41 bits: (2^41)-1 = 2199023255551 ms
- Divided by (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 ) ms/year = 69 years

So, where am I wrong?

Comment: Your math checks out, so it's either a typo or they are doing something with those bits other than what you and I think they're doing. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef thanks. It was making me feel stupid/driving me crazy.

Comment: Google `milliseconds 2199023255551`, many results support your theory

Comment: Perhaps their epoch was 28 years ago (at the time of writing) and they are saying they have 41 years left. (I find it handy to remember: there are pi seconds in a nano-century. (Accurate to better than 1%).)

Comment: how does custom epoch affect this, why do they mention customer epoch, do ew not need to subtract the milliseconds used up until the start of their epoch.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're not wrong about the calculation.

```
(2^41)-1 ms
    == 2199023255.551 s
    == 610839.7932086 hr 
    == 25451.65805036 days 
    == 69.6828 Julian years 
    == 69.6843 Gregorian Years
```

Which lines up closely with your result (`69 years`).

However, the website you link to does say that `41 bits` gives them

> 41 years of IDs with a custom epoch

"Epoch" in this context is probably referring to the start date. Given that that article was published "3 years ago", or in `2012`, we can calculate that their epoch begins in `2012 + 41 - 69 == 1984`. This date was possibly chosen as [a reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four).

Comment: What program did you use to get that output?

Comment: Oh I just hand typed it. I probably did the conversions either in Google or by hand

Comment: Can  any one tell me why we substract - 1

Comment: @rookie subtracted 1 to discard 0 value.

Comment: Hmm, since Postgres doesn't support unsigned BIGINTs, wouldn't the first bit effectively be useless in order to maintain the sortable by time criteria? Otherwise, at 2^40ms past the chosen epoch, the bigint would presumably go negative. That gives les than 35 years then, no?

Comment: @rookie i believe 2^41 would require 42 bytes to store. So 2^41 - 1 is the maximum amount you could store in this range. But like qix says, since Postgres doesn't support unsigned BigInts with the most significant bit being used to represent negative numbers they can use that list but will surely lose being able to order by them, as the number will turn negative